# DVD Share on Vista Home Premium Failing

Tags: windows-vista

UPDATE:
-   I can't find any Local Policy Editor for Vista Home Premium, as suggested.
-   I did learn about registry keys:  allocatecdroms, allocatefloppies, allocatedasd and tried adding these keys (individually and collectively) and setting them to both 0 or 1.  There was no positive affect on read access to the DVD root folder - always Access Denied.

ORIGINAL POST:
Failing read access to the root folder of a DVD drive in Vista Home Premium laptop using the Guest account - Access Denied.  The client is an XP Home PC that can see, but not access, the data in the share.

I'm only trying to read the data DVD - not trying to write/burn anything.

On the Vista laptop, I have:

- All Firewalls and Antivirus disabled.UAC disabled.
- Password checking disabled.
- "Advanced Shared" the DVD drive, with "Everyone" having full-access permissions to the share.
- Tried adding Guest and Anonymous users having full-access permissions to the share.
- RestrictAnonymous=0 set in the registry.
- Both PC's are in the same workgroup (MSHOME)

The XP Home client sees the shared DVD in \Vista_Hostname\ but when I double click the drive icon on the client, I get a popup that access is denied, check with the administrator, etc.

I can share other folders on the Vista PC and see and READ these from the XP Home client.

If I enable password checking on the Vista side, I get a user/password popup, and I can authenticate (using my known Vista account, that happens to have Admin rights) and then I can get to see and read the DVD data.

I need to open this up so that the (default) Guest user can see and access the DVD data files.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your local security policy.  (Local Policies --> Security Options). One of the options concerns restricting access to the CDROM/DVD.  Check your setting.

Comment: Would surprise me if "Devices: Restrict CD-ROM access to locally logged-on user only" is enabled.

Comment: The other possibility is "Network access: sharing model and security for local accounts", which is probably already defined as "Classic - local users authenticate themselves".

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to try, a bit contradictory to what you did:

1. Verify the checklist in this [article](http://blog.proud-geek.com/2007/04/02/windows-vista-annoyance-3-file-folder-sharing-between-computers-on-a-network/) on the Vista machine.
2. The article [Enable Simple File Sharing in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/126910-simple-file-sharing-enable.html) contains many steps that you should mostly follow through.  It might be better to turn off password protected sharing as described in this article.